# Is there an excel functions helps me count the values in two different columns if either or condition is met?

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the number of claims for members whose claims amounts are greater than zero. If there are dollar amounts that show up in either column, I want to count that as "1". I included a screenshot of what I am trying to do.

[image: Practice Code]

As you can see in the picture, I am using the following excel formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(E6:E8,">0",F6:F8,">0")
```

The above formula is getting me half of what I need. Whenever there is any amount in BOTH of the columns highlighted in yellow, the formula returns a count. However, I want the formula to return a count if there are amounts in EITHER columns, not both.

Any advice or guidance would help.

Comment: What about `=COUNTIFS(E6:E8,">0")+COUNTIFS(F6:F8,">0")-COUNTIFS(E6:E8,">0",F6:F8,">0")` if you don't want to double count rows that have a value in both columns.

Comment: If by *count if there are amounts in EITHER columns, not both.* you really mean *count  of 1 if there are amounts in EITHER columns or both*, you could use `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(1/((E6:E8>0)+(F6:F8>0))))`